# Why is only mole fraction used in Henry's law and not some other measure of concentration?

Tags: solubility, mole

Why is some other quantity like molality or molarity used?
I understand why mass percentage cannot be used as it is difficult to measure mass of gas...
Now is mole fraction used because solubility is directly proportional to the pressure and moles are directly proportional to the pressure?

Also, how do they measure the number of moles of a gas?

Comment: There are multiple ways to express Henry's law (which originate different but equivalent Henry's law constants), some of which involve mole fraction, others use concentrations in mol/L.

Comment: Okay thank you but then will the unit of Henry's law constant change?

Comment: Yes, it changes accordingly.